# Python Dash Core Components Graph() with Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly-dash

What is the relationship between Dash Core Components Graph() and Plotly Express?

For example, I can create a graph with

```
dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": data["DateTime"],
                        "y": data["Gold"],
                        "type": "lines",
                    },
                ],
                "layout": {
                    "title": "Gold Price"
                },
            },
        )
```

but many of the tutorials I've seen use plotly express in conjunction with dcc.Graph(), so it doesn't appear to be an either/or situation.

Is it a bad idea to just use dcc.Graph()? What would the advantage be of using plotly express as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using plotly express is that it’s easier to make a figure. I use dash a lot and I’ve never made a dcc.Graph() building it like you described. I’ve always used express or graph_objects. Either way, when you make a the dcc graph object is the same after it’s made.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Could you possibly show me how I would achieve the same result as in my example with plotly express?

Comment: Sure.
`dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(x=data['DateTime'], y=data['Gold'], title='Gold Price'))`